# How to split a .gif in frames?

Tags: c#, image, frame, gif

All the codes I've found give me the same result: a bunch of exact looking frames. Meaning: it gives me a list of the first frame, repeated X number of times. The .gif I'm using has 30 frames, so I get 30 times the first frame, instead of the 30 different frames.

```
    public static Image[] GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(Image IMG)
    {
        List<Image> IMGs = new List<Image>();
        int Length = IMG.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            IMG.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
            IMGs.Add(IMG);
        }

        return IMGs.ToArray();
    }
```

What am I missing? ALL the codes I've looked give the first frame repeated X numbers of times.

This is what is supposed to look (using a webpage). See how each frame is different?

[image]

This is what it looks for me after saving every frame inside that array on a folder location (a bunch of equal frames):

[image]

P.S.: Yes, it's a .gif the image I'm using.

Update: The problem seems to be when I read the file in the OpenFileDialog, as it works if I pass my .gif by code. So how do I read an animated gif in the OpenFileDialong? Thank you.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951786/wpf-how-to-extract-frames-from-multiframe-images-tif-gif?rq=1

Comment: @aisa Thank you, but now it turned out that if I pass my .gif by code it works. So the problem is in the OpenFileDialog, as it's reading my animated .gif as an simple .gif.

Comment: Have you tried using [`GifBitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from WPF?

Comment: +dbc Sadly, this requires no WPF use. It's for an old PC.

Comment: Looking at the code you should be getting 30 times *last* frame as you have list of the same object repeated 30 times (and last call is `MG.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, 30);`). You should be saving "current frame" somehow (I don't know how to do that - just your code looks incomplete that way).

Comment: +Alexei Levenkov I was already helped, thank you. I was told to change `IMGs.Add(IMG)` for `IMGs.Add(new Bitmap(IMG))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   IMGs.Add(IMG);
```

That's the bug, you are adding the same IMG object over and over again.  You need to make a deep copy of the frame.  That's very easy to do:

```
   IMGs.Add(new Bitmap(IMG));
```

Comment: And all those copies will need to be disposed later.

Comment: So that's what the problem was. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. Now I'm just left wondering why on earth the .Net framework pretends they're paletteless 32-bit RGBA instead of 8-bit paletted.

Comment: Sure, using that Bitmap constructor will get you a pixel format that matches the setting of your monitor.  Meant to be optimal.